# flask TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, html, forms, authentication, flask

Can someone say what is wrong with this code? The error which I get:

> TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable

```
def login():
error = None
form = LoginForm(request.form)

if request.method == 'POST':
    viewer = User.query.filter_by(Group='viewer').first()
    admin = User.query.filter_by(Group='admin').first()
    staff = User.query.filter_by(Group='staff').first()
    user = User.query.filter_by(Email=request.form(['email'])).first()
    password = User.query.filter_by(Password=request.form(['password'])).first()
    if (user or password) is None:
        session['logged_in'] = False
        flash('Please write your username password')
    else:

                session['logged_in'] = True
                flash('You were logged in')
                if viewer:
                    return redirect(url_for('viewer'))
                elif admin :
                    return redirect(url_for('admin'))
                elif staff:
                    return redirect(url_for('employee'))

return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

And this is an html part:

```
<form class="sa-innate-form" method="post">
                            {{ form.csrf_token }}
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ request.form.email }}">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}">
                            <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign In</button>
                            <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(Email=request.form(['email'])).first()
```

Instead it should be:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(Email=request.form['email']).first()
```

There are a few other instances of this so make sure you catch all of them. The reason this is an error is you are trying to call `request.form` with the string list `['email']` instead of indexing into the form.

`if (user or password) is None:` is also buggy. If either one is not `None`, then the block will not be triggered. However, I believe that the desired behavior is to require both. You could try either this:

```
if user is None or password is None:
```

or:

```
if None in [user, password]:
```

Comment: Adam thank you so much. I just realized all errors after reading your comment. Again thanks, it was very helpful